# DsPack Stop Position

Tags: delphi, dspack

I need to play some video via DsPack from StartPosition to EndPosition. I have written a simple piece of code that allows to specify StartPosition:

```
  FilterGraph1.Active := true;
  VideoWindow1.FilterGraph:= FilterGraph1;
  FilterGraph1.RenderFile('C:\Users\idsa\Documents\ENGLISH_2\ENGLISH_2\0001\0.avi');
  FilterGraph1.Position := 10000;
  FilterGraph1.Play;
```

But how can I specify StopPosition?

Comment: Something like `(FilterGraph as IMediaSeeking).SetPositions(..., Stop, AM_ABSOLUTE)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks **FreeConsulting** for a hint. Here is the final code.

```
uses DirectShow9;

...

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  MediaSeeking: IMediaSeeking;
  Start: Int64;
  Stop: Int64;
begin
  FilterGraph1.Active := true;
  VideoWindow1.FilterGraph:= FilterGraph1;
  FilterGraph1.RenderFile('fileName');
  FilterGraph1.QueryInterface(IMediaSeeking, MediaSeeking);

  Start := 0;
  Stop := 10 * 10000000;

  MediaSeeking.SetPositions(Start, AM_SEEKING_AbsolutePositioning, Stop, AM_SEEKING_AbsolutePositioning);

  FilterGraph1.Play;
end;
```

Comment: Ok, but why did you drop `as` operator? It is clear and concise and does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Thank your !
I can make loop on DSP !!!

```
    procedure TForm1.FilterGraphLGraphComplete(Sender: TObject;
  Result: HRESULT; Renderer: IBaseFilter);

var
  MediaSeeking: DirectShow9.IMediaSeeking;
  Start: Int64;
  Stop: Int64;
begin
  FilterGraphL.QueryInterface(IMediaSeeking, MediaSeeking);

  Start := 0;
  Stop := 10 * 10000000;

  MediaSeeking.SetPositions(Start, AM_SEEKING_AbsolutePositioning, Stop, AM_SEEKING_NoPositioning);
```

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34821344)